# swagger-tools validate hangs when using external ref with absolute URLs

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am currently breaking down a swagger.json file following this guide: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/guidelines/REUSE.md

I made a mistake somewhere, and I would like to use the swagger-tools to find out where is my problem. When I run the tool, it just get stuck and doesn't produce any output.

I am using a localhost server, and my $ref are pointing to the localhost using absolute URLs such as:

```
"$ref": "http://localhost:8080/api-docs/v1/parameters.json#/myParameter"
```

I tried running using the file from the filesystem or served by the local server: none is working.

```
swagger-tools validate http://localhost:8080/api-docs/v1/swagger.json
```

However, if I shutdown the server and try to validate from the file system, the tools complains that it cannot resolve the references so somehow that proves that the file is parsed and swagger-tools tries to validate it.

- Platform: Windows 7 Pro
- Powershell
- npm --version: 2.11.3
- swagger-tools --version: 0.9.2
- installed using npm -g install

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the problem was coming from self-references in the definitions file that were using absolute URLs.

Using relative reference such as:

```
"$ref" : "#/myReference"
```

solved the issue and the swagger-tools validate is now working as expected.

I started suspecting something like that when I looked at the Node.js process and saw it was consuming 1.2 Go RAM and 25% CPU.